# Long Title attribute text is getting cut off in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using HTML5. I am setting title attribute text dynamically using J query. If I have a title attribute with a long text in it (while the HTML element is truncated) the tool-tip gets cut off. This happens only in Firefox (only tested version 37.0) In chrome and Internet explorer it is displaying complete title attribute long text.
HTML code is

```
<table id="notify_time">
     <tr>
         <td style="padding-right:10px;width:10px"> 
               <div class="time">${notificationEntry.time}</div>
         </td>
         <td>
               <div class="desc">${notificationEntry.content}</div>
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code is :

```
$('.desc').bind('mouseenter', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if(this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth && !$this.attr('title')){
        $this.attr('title', $this.text());
    }
});
```

CSS code is

```
.desc {
max-width: 235px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
cursor: default;
font-size: 12px
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete JSFiddle example? I have started one for you: https://jsfiddle.net/4ceq4dp3/3/

Comment: yes Marc. here it is https://jsfiddle.net/4ceq4dp3/4/

Comment: Here is what I see in my tooltip on Firefox 37: https://cldup.com/1C_r5msO8r.png

It seems like the title attribute is only truncated when inspecting the HTML element. In all other cases, the full title attribute is shown.

Comment: @MarcB. In my case title attribute is truncating on OS windows8 and windows7 Firefox 37. Title attribute is not truncating in OS Ubuntu , Firefox version 37